# Remove a character from a dynamic textfield

Tags: actionscript-3

I am very new to scripting. I am trying to make a dialer for my android phone.

I have a dynamic text box on stage and 10 buttons,( 0-9 ). I was able to program the buttons to add the numbers to the text field using( +=). Then, I programmed a delete button to remove the numbers. It removes all the numbers at once, which is what I don't want.

I would like it to remove the last character that was put in. Also, I would like to group the numbers in sets of 3, 3, 4 (000 000 0000).
Any ideas on how to do these two things would be greatly appreciated.

thank  you for helping me out. I was able to add the code you gave to me and the remove last character worked great but ive tried putting in the code for grouping and spacing the numbers everyway except the right way I guess. how do I get this to work im sure it will with a little help

one_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, n1click);

function n1click(event:MouseEvent):void{
    if(n1click)
    input_txt.text +=("1");
}
input_txt.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onFieldChange); //once our textfield is changed, this listener will fire

```
function onFieldChange(e:Event):void {
    if(field.length % (groupBy + 1) == 0) { //if the modulo of our groupBy + 1 is 0 => we have 4, 8, 12, etc.. chars in our field
        field.text = field.text.substr(0, field.text.length - 1) + " " + field.text.charAt(field.text.length - 1); //insert the space before the last character
        field.setSelection(field.text.length, field.text.length); //set the caret at the end of the text
    }
}
```

Comment: Who is "Andre Silva"? And if you have a question about a response, comment it under the response, not under your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried anything? It can be achieved in different ways, here is one:

```
var field:TextField = this.field; //field is on the timeline, just retrieving the instance
var groupBy:uint = 3; //let's use this to show groups of 3 numbers

field.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onFieldChange); //once our textfield is changed, this listener will fire

function onFieldChange(e:Event):void {
    if(field.length % (groupBy + 1) == 0) { //if the modulo of our groupBy + 1 is 0 => we have 4, 8, 12, etc.. chars in our field
        field.text = field.text.substr(0, field.text.length - 1) + " " + field.text.charAt(field.text.length - 1); //insert the space before the last character
        field.setSelection(field.text.length, field.text.length); //set the caret at the end of the text
    }
}

function deleteLastChar():void {
    if(field.text.charAt(field.text.length - 2) == " ") { //if it is the first char of the group (=means it has a space before)
        field.text = field.text.slice(0, -2); //remove the last character and the space
    }
    else {
        field.text = field.text.slice(0, -1); //remove only the last char
    }
    field.setSelection(field.text.length, field.text.length); //and once again set the caret (if necessary)
}
```